# How can I teleport players to start if they touch these blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a flying map where players are not allowed to touch grass, quartz, or leaves. If they do, I need them to be teleported to the start. How can I do that? By the way, this is 15w47c map.

Comment: Get player locations, check Y maybe?

Comment: I edited it, so it is no longer a duplicate of the linked question. Could we get some moderators to start a reopen vote?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:grass -1 tp @a[c=1] <x> <y> <z>
```

That checks if the player is on top of a grass block. Just change the relative coordinates (the `~ ~-1 ~`) in order to check above, right, etc. And, obviously, change `minecraft:grass` to whatever block you want to check. If you have issues with the relative coords, check them out [here](http://www.planetminecraft.com/forums/setblock-players-coords-commandblock-help-t311280.html).

Comment: I'm not an expert on commands but there's a "not equal" check too, right? So you could test instead that they're not above air?

Comment: @Studoku Well, you could just put `execute @a ~ ~ ~ testfor @e[type=Air] ~ ~1 ~` and put a redstone inverter circuit next to the comparator. There probably is a way to put not equal, but this is easier :P

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd guess !=

Comment: @Studoku Does my solution work? Also, `!=` is the operator in many programming languages for not equal to, so that's a good guess!

Comment: The `@e` selector (as well as `/testfor`) is to target entities. The `type` parameter specifies an entity ID ([list](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Data_values/Entity_IDs)). Blocks are not entities and no target selector can target blocks. You must use a command that works with blocks, such as `/testforblock`, but `/execute` has syntax for detecting a block anyway: `/execute <target> X Y Z detect X Y Z <block> <Damage> <command>`

Answer (score 0):

The `OnGround` byte tag specifies whether or not the player is on the ground. You can assign a score based on its value and target the player based on that score:

```
/scoreboard objectives add OnGround dummy

/scoreboard players set @a OnGround 1 {OnGround:1b}
/scoreboard players set @a OnGround 0 {OnGround:0b}

/tp @a[score_OnGround_min=1] X Y Z
```

Another method is to detect whether there is air at the player's current feet position, but keep in mind that this method is flawed when it comes to players standing on non-full blocks such as slabs:

```
/scoreboard players set @a OnGround 1
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ minecraft:air 0 scoreboard players set @a[c=1] OnGround 0
```

---

For 15w47c+, you can use the "tags" feature to avoid having to use scoreboard objectives:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=!OnGround] add OnGround {OnGround:1b}
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=OnGround] remove OnGround {OnGround:0b}

/tp @a[tag=OnGround] X Y Z
```